# Postgres 14 Backslash Z is not giving the correct output

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am logged into the Postgres14 Windows server using psql and as the postgres super-user. However, when I type in \z or \dp I don't get the same output as I do in my MAC. I get the following
training=# \dp+
Access privileges

| Schema | Name | Type | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| public | accounts | table |  |  |  |
| public | address | table |  |  |  |

I don't see any roles (postgres or others that I made). In my MAC I get the expected results with postgres super-user having all the privileges on tables and my regular user none.
Can someone help? I re-installed postgres to the latest version and restarted it a bunch of times.
Thanks

Comment: Here is the output from my MAC:
training=# \z
                                                  Access privileges
 Schema |   Name    | Type  |     Access privileges     |  Column privileges  |               Policies
--------+-----------+-------+---------------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------
 public | people    | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+| name:              +| nojoe:                              +
        |           |       | user1=arwdDxt/postgres   +|   user4=rw/postgres+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal and (surprisingly) means that the tables have the default privileges: the owner has all permissions and everybody else has no permissions. If you grant extra privileges, you will see something in the `\dp` output.

Comment: LOL...yes I see it now. Thank you.
 public | people            | table             | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres+|                   |
        |                   |                   | user1=r/postgres          |                   |